# KDE Framework 5 buid problem on Beyond Linux From Scratch

Tags: lfs, kde5

I was building KDE Framework 5 according to the BLFS book Version 2016-02-16.
The link is here http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/kde/krameworks5.html

But the build process stoppd at `kcompletion`.
The error is given below:

```
[ 92%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/KF5Completion.dir/kcompletionbox.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/KF5Completion.dir/klineedit.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:37:0,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:41,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qobject.h:40,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/QObject:1,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/kcompletion.h:25,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.h:33,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:28:
/usr/include/kconfiggroup.h: In member function ‘QList<T> KConfigGroup::readListCheck(const char*, const QList<T>&) const’:
/usr/include/kconfiggroup.h:740:5: error: ‘qVariantCanConvert’ was not declared in this scope
     Q_ASSERT(qVariantCanConvert<T>(value));
     ^
/usr/include/kconfiggroup.h:740:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     Q_ASSERT(qVariantCanConvert<T>(value));
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/kstandardshortcut.h:25:0,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:36:
/usr/include/kshortcut.h: In function ‘uint qHash(const KShortcut&)’:
/usr/include/kshortcut.h:248:34: error: call of overloaded ‘qHash(int)’ is ambiguous
     return qHash(key.primary()[0]) + qHash(key.primary()[1]);
                                  ^
In file included from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qshareddata.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:39,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qpointer.h:37,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/QPointer:1,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/kcompletion.h:27,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.h:33,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:28:
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:65:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(char, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(char key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:66:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(uchar, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(uchar ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:67:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(signed char, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(signed c
                                                    ^
In file included from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qshareddata.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:39,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qpointer.h:37,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/QPointer:1,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/kcompletion.h:27,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.h:33,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:28:
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:68:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(ushort, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(ushort k
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:69:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(short int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(short ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:70:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(uint, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(uint key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:71:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(int key,
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:72:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(ulong, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(ulong ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:78:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(long int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(long key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:79:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(quint64, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(quint64 
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:83:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(qint64, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(qint64 k
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:84:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(float, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(float key, uint se
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:85:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(double, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(double key, uint s
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:87:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(long double, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(long double key, u
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:89:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(QChar, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(const QC
                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/kstandardshortcut.h:25:0,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:36:
/usr/include/kshortcut.h:245:6: note: candidate: uint qHash(int)
 uint qHash(int);
      ^
/usr/include/kshortcut.h:248:60: error: call of overloaded ‘qHash(int)’ is ambiguous
     return qHash(key.primary()[0]) + qHash(key.primary()[1]);
                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qshareddata.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:39,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qpointer.h:37,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/QPointer:1,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/kcompletion.h:27,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.h:33,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:28:
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:65:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(char, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(char key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:66:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(uchar, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(uchar ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:67:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(signed char, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(signed c
                                                    ^
In file included from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qshareddata.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:39,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qpointer.h:37,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/QPointer:1,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/kcompletion.h:27,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.h:33,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:28:
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:68:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(ushort, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(ushort k
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:69:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(short int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(short ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:70:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(uint, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(uint key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:71:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(int key,
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:72:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(ulong, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(ulong ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:78:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(long int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(long key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:79:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(quint64, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(quint64 
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:83:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(qint64, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(qint64 k
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:84:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(float, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(float key, uint se
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:85:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(double, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(double key, uint s
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:87:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(long double, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(long double key, u
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:89:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(QChar, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(const QC
                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/kstandardshortcut.h:25:0,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:36:
/usr/include/kshortcut.h:245:6: note: candidate: uint qHash(int)
 uint qHash(int);
      ^
/usr/include/kshortcut.h: In function ‘uint qHash(const QKeySequence&)’:
/usr/include/kshortcut.h:255:28: error: call of overloaded ‘qHash(int)’ is ambiguous
        hash += qHash(key[i]);
                            ^
In file included from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qshareddata.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:39,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qpointer.h:37,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/QPointer:1,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/kcompletion.h:27,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.h:33,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:28:
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:65:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(char, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(char key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:66:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(uchar, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(uchar ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:67:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(signed char, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(signed c
                                                    ^
In file included from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qshareddata.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:39,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qpointer.h:37,
                 from /opt/qt5/include/QtCore/QPointer:1,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/kcompletion.h:27,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.h:33,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:28:
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:68:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(ushort, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(ushort k
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:69:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(short int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(short ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:70:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(uint, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(uint key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:71:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(int key,
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:72:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(ulong, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(ulong ke
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:78:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(long int, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(long key
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:79:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(quint64, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(quint64 
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:83:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(qint64, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(qint64 k
                                                    ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:84:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(float, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(float key, uint se
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:85:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(double, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(double key, uint s
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:87:42: note: candidate: uint qHash(long double, uint)
 Q_CORE_EXPORT Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION uint qHash(long double key, u
                                          ^
/opt/qt5/include/QtCore/qhash.h:89:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(QChar, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(const QC
                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/kstandardshortcut.h:25:0,
                 from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:36:
/usr/include/kshortcut.h:245:6: note: candidate: uint qHash(int)
 uint qHash(int);
      ^
/usr/include/kshortcut.h:251:13: note: candidate: uint qHash(const QKeySequence&)
 inline uint qHash(const QKeySequence &key)
             ^
In file included from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1671:0:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit.cpp: In static member function ‘static void KLineEdit::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)’:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit.cpp:287:74: warning: ‘bool KLineEdit::isContextMenuEnabled() const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 reinterpret_cast< bool*>(_v) = _t->isContextMenuEnabled(); break;
                                                         ^
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1630:6: note: declared here
 bool KLineEdit::isContextMenuEnabled() const
      ^
In file included from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1671:0:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit.cpp:291:69: warning: ‘QString KLineEdit::clickMessage() const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  4: *reinterpret_cast< QString*>(_v) = _t->clickMessage(); break;
                                                         ^
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:207:9: note: declared here
 QString KLineEdit::clickMessage() const
         ^
In file included from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1671:0:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit.cpp:301:72: warning: ‘virtual void KLineEdit::setContextMenuEnabled(bool)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  _t->setContextMenuEnabled(*reinterpret_cast< bool*>(_v)); break;
                                                         ^
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1623:6: note: declared here
 void KLineEdit::setContextMenuEnabled(bool showMenu)
      ^
In file included from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1671:0:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit.cpp:302:69: warning: ‘void KLineEdit::setUrlDropsEnabled(bool)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  1: _t->setUrlDropsEnabled(*reinterpret_cast< bool*>(_v)); break;
                                                         ^
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1263:6: note: declared here
 void KLineEdit::setUrlDropsEnabled(bool enable)
      ^
In file included from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1671:0:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit.cpp:305:69: warning: ‘void KLineEdit::setClickMessage(const QString&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  4: _t->setClickMessage(*reinterpret_cast< QString*>(_v)); break;
                                                         ^
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1616:6: note: declared here
 void KLineEdit::setClickMessage(const QString &msg)
      ^
In file included from /mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1672:0:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit_p.cpp: At global scope:
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/build/src/moc_klineedit_p.cpp:199:1: warning: ‘virtual void KLineEdit::setContextMenuEnabled(bool)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 }
 ^
/mnt/mnt/lfs/kcompletion-5.18.0/src/klineedit.cpp:1623:6: note: declared here
 void KLineEdit::setContextMenuEnabled(bool showMenu)
      ^
src/CMakeFiles/KF5Completion.dir/build.make:158: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/KF5Completion.dir/klineedit.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/KF5Completion.dir/klineedit.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3949: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/KF5Completion.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/KF5Completion.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Are you trying to install KF5 independent of KDE4? Or are you trying to build it along with KDE4?

Comment: independent of KDE4 @munircontractor

Comment: I see a lot of `/mnt/mnt/lfs` in the errors. Are you building this in a `chroot` environment? 
Also, send a mail to the BLFS support mailing list. Someone there might be able to help.

Comment: @munircontractor well, I have the source file in /dev/sda4/mnt/lfs which is mounted on /mnt

Comment: https://github.com/haraldF/homebrew-kf5/issues/8 - might be relevant to you

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. In his case the error was that it couldn't find a required file. But mine doesn't show any specific error. It just failed

Comment: Your case also has an error. Look at ~10th line in your post: `/usr/include/kconfiggroup.h:740:5: error: ‘qVariantCanConvert’ was not declared in this scope`. There's always an error whenever a build fails, it's just hard to trace it. Usually, running `make -j1` will make tracing errors easier.